# Different Firefox installations receiving different cookies (from the same page)

Tags: firefox, cookies, missing-cookies

I was wondering if anyone could think of a reason why two freshly-installed Firefox installations on different machines might be receiving a wildly different amount of cookies when visiting the same site.  I know there's a limit to how many cookies can be dropped per request, so I'm actually hitting the same page about 10 times, accumulating all the cookies as I go.

My two Firefox installations **are** different versions (10 and 16), but I'm not sure how much that should matter.  I can't seem to find much helpful information on the web, as "Firefox isn't putting enough cookies on my machine" doesn't seem to be a popular search.  :)  Both Firefox installations are completely fresh though- I didn't change any settings from the defaults.

I've already requested that our IT-Ops folks upgrade the box to FF16, but it will take some time.  I just thought that in the meantime, maybe somebody might know of some super-secret warranty-voiding 'about:config' entry that might be related to accepting cookies, or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firefox upgrade did the trick.  Not sure if it was due to default security settings differences between 10 and 16, but I'm now seeing all the cookies consistently across both machines.